# Mongoose - can't save a document's properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have users and teams. I would like teams to have an array of users and I add a user to the team using the addUser function. I push to the teams user array successfully and save the results but right after that function I go to print out the same team and there are no users in the array. I am not sure if this is a .save() problem or what.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
...

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  age: Number
});
var teamSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  user: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
userSchema.statics.createUser = function(opts, cb) {...};
teamSchema.statics.createTeam = function(opts, cb) {...};

teamSchema.statics.addUser = function(opts, cb) {
  Team.find({_id: opts.team}).exec( function (err, team) {
    team[0].user.push(opts.user);
    team[0].save(function(err, save) {
        console.log("--------------------");
        console.log(team[0]); //team contains the added user here
        console.log("--------------------");
        return cb(null);
    });
  });
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);   

var async = require('async');
var user1;
var user2;
var team;

async.waterfall([
  function(d){User.createUser({name :'test1'},function(err, user){
            user1 = user;
            d(err);
  });
  },

  function(d){User.createUser({name :'test2',age :20},function(err, user){
            user2 = user;
            d(err);
  });
  },

  function(d){Team.createTeam({name :'team'},function(err, obj){
            team = obj;
            d(err);
  });
  },
  function(d){Team.addUser({user : user1._id,team : team._id},   function(err){
            console.log(team);
            d(err);
  });
  },
  function(d){Team.addUser({user : user2._id,team : team._id},      function(err){
                console.log(team);
                d(err);
  });
  }

 ],function(err){
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      User.count({},function(err,count){console.log("Number of users:", count);});
      Team.count({},function(err,count){console.log("Number of teams:", count);});
      console.log(team);
    }

  });


returns:
--------------------
{ _id: 5583ed760958ab941a58bae9,
  name: 'team',
  __v: 1,
  user: [ 5583ed760958ab941a58bae7 ] } //user1 added
--------------------
{ __v: 0, name: 'team', _id: 5583ed760958ab941a58bae9, user: [] }
 //after that function call the team has no users
--------------------
{ _id: 5583ed760958ab941a58bae9,
  name: 'team',
  __v: 2,
  user: [ 5583ed760958ab941a58bae7, 5583ed760958ab941a58bae8 ] } 
//user2 added and user1 still there
--------------------
{ __v: 0, name: 'team', _id: 5583ed760958ab941a58bae9, user: [] } //no users again
Number of users: 2
Number of teams: 1 //only 1 team exists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try using an update and push which would also simplify your code?

[findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) (mongodb command)

[findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) (mongoose command)

```
Team.findOneAndUpdate({"_id" : opts.team} , {$addToSet : { "user" : opts.user}}, function (err, foundUpdatedTeam) {
  return cb(err,foundUpdatedTeam);
}, {new : true});

// be sure to update your team variable to reflect what is also in the database.
```

something like this:

```
function(d){Team.addUser({user : user1._id,team : team._id},   function(err, updatedTeam)        
{
  team = updatedTeam;
  console.log(team);
  d(err);
});
```

Few Notes:

1. I would change the team schema from user to TeamUsers or something more descriptive..it's a little confusing now.
2. note the use of [AddToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/), that ensures that if you already added the user you won't be adding him twice.
3. This code is shorter and cleaner, you don't need to find the object if you can use the dedicated function, if however you wish to add the user to multiple teams I'd use update which allows you to update multiple documents.

Comment: I seem to run into the same problem where the users are being added but at the end there are no users on the team.

Comment: of course, as the updateOne doesn't return the new updated document unless you ask for it..check out the documentation.. I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: plus you have another problem, I think you do not return the team variable for the update object. Just to be safe, you can also just query for the team after you finish all the loop, I'd also suggest you run a mongo console and check what happens to the team in the database, as that will show you where the error is (as I believe it is that way).

Comment: @Albo please try the changes I made and see if it works now ?

Comment: Yeah it works now, I never set the team to the updated team. Thanks so much for your help.